# USB3 transmitting video to USB-C

Tags: usb, video-adapters, usb-c

I have a setup where I am planning on using a USB-C switcher to send a signal to a dock that uses display cables to send video to two monitors. The USB-C switcher is intended to take a signal from my laptop or my PC so I can switch the monitors between displaying the laptop or PC output.

The issue is, I do not have a USB-C port on my PC, and I cannot find a USB3->USB-C adapter or cable that also transmits video. Can anyone point me to one? It needs to send a video output via USB3 *to* USB-C (I clarify this because I’ve found the opposite, but that does not work for my needs).

Answer (score 0):

In theory, your idea will not work. USB video is actually done using DisplayPort or Thunderbolt. Unless you are an extreme tweaker and create something like USB to DP yourself, I would reccomend plugging in the cables manually... :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch). You can use a KVM switch to control two computers with one set of peripherals.  An example of this would be using two monitors, a keyboard and a mouse plugged into the KVM switch and two computers plugged into the KVM switch as well.  On the KVM switch, you can click a button and all the peripherals switch between the computers.

USB 3.0 (or C for that matter) won't have enough bandwidth to handle even two monitors, much less all the peripherals you would need to plug into the computer as well.  You would need thunderbolt for that, which does run on USB C, but if you don't have a USB C port on your computer, you definitely don't have a thunderbolt port on it (unless you are using a MacBook from before 2015).  Also, I have a USB 3.0 to VGA adapter that does work at 1080p, but it has around a 100ms delay so it isn't a good experience.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC is easy you can buy a PCIe adapter to plug into your motherboard that provides a USB type C plug.

Laptops don't have this ability.